# SAPUI5: How to set parent visibility in XML

Tags: javascript, xml, model-view-controller, sapui5

I do have the following  SimpleForm:

```
<f:SimpleForm columnsL="3" columnsM="3">
    <f:content>

        <core:Title id="idExample" text="Hello World"/>
        <ScrollContainer xmlns="sap.m" horizontal="true">
          <content>
            <Label text ="Hello World" />
          </content>
        </ScrollContainer>

   </f:content>
<f:SimpleForm>
```

the whole **Section** composed of `<core:Title>`  and `<ScrollContainer>` can be setVisibile in the controller with the following:

```
this.getView().byId("idExample").getParent().setVisible(false);
```

What should be added to the `<core:Title>` in terms of Attributes in order to achieve the equivalent but in the View-Page?

Comment: Use a local JSONModel. Much less trouble. Also who puts a ScrollContainer in a SimpleForm?

Answer (score 0):

`<core:Title>` does not have a property for visibility.
By virtue of `.getParent()` you are setting the visibility of `SimpleForm` (the parent control to `Title`) to `false` (and not `Title`).
The XML View equivalent would therefore be: `<f:SimpleForm visible="false" ...`

These values are best controlled through a model that manages the view's state - oftentimes you will see people use a `JSONModel` name viewModel

Hope that helps

Comment: Hey, thank you for your comment @Bernard!!! The Problem is, when setting `<f:SimpleForm visible="false">` the `<core:Title>` with `text="Hello World"`, doesn't dissapear, however with `<this.getView().byId("idExample").getParent().setVisible(false);` it does.

Comment: You could enclose the simpleform within a panel or a VBox and affect the visibility there? - I will have to dig into this in detail to see where the visibility is being affected without those.